# Open source application(s) for tomcat that use jdbc

Tags: web-apps, java, php, jdbc

There are a lot of open-source projects such as Wordpress, vBulletin, Fusion Ticket, Front Accounting, etc. These are all web applications devised for LAMP platforms, i.e., they are developed in the PHP language and use PDO to access a database (and typically demand a MySQL engine).

However, I am seeking applications like the ones I described, but that are written in Java (hence requiring Apache Tomcat) and access their databases using JDBC (preferably accessing a Postgresql engine). Also like the examples I mentioned, I also need them to be open source. If you know about an application that also fits the criteria but is not an example of the ones I gave, I would also like to learn about it.

Many thanks in advance.

Added: Found what I was looking for:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue-tracking_systems

http://technethub.com/ecommerce/java-open-source-ecommerce-software-platforms-applications-framework/

Added: found more:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_shopping_cart_software

http://www.cio.com/article/2400389/open-source-tools/10-open-source-shopping-carts-to-run-your-ecommerce-business.html

Comment: I think this question might be off-topic here (related Meta discussion: [Is looking for software as “data” within our scope?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1095/60)). You don’t seem to require *recommendations* but just a list of software matching some technical requirements.

Comment: I have to agree with unor here. Key sentence is: ***"What exactly the application does is not that relevant,*** as long as it accesses a database and performs transactions." Much too broad at least for this site – basically, a JSP page with some SQL embedded would fit it as well as a feature-richt application. The linked question on Meta applies here.

Comment: I re-wrote the question to make it more specific.

Comment: Where should something like this be asked? Stack Overflow vigilantes might have a conniption and fall on the floor seething, potentially using up precious ambulance and paramedic time if they saw a question like this, so you'd think this would be the place, no?

Comment: The fact that more time is being devoted to debating wether or not my question is off-topic than actually giving me a answer is... ironic?

Comment: Edited again the question to add links with the type of software I was looking for.

Comment: http://www.liferay.com/  is a portal software that includes a content management system, online forums and a lot more. I can use Postgres and needs a Tomcat server (actually it comes bundled with one)